# How to create xpath to select book?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, firepath

Here I am struggling to finding `xpath` to select the text `Book` from below Images for Web content and DOM

[image]

[image]

Advice me how to select book text.

I have done up to this point.  May be its  strait forward

Xpath I created is :

```
//*[@class='four columns m-r-3']//following-sibling::h2/strong
```

[image of web content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXRpa.png)

Comment: well this XPath selects the <strong> tags, just check if the text is book

Comment: i did like this >>>>>>>> .//*[@class='four columns m-r-3']//following-sibling::h2/strong[text()='Book']   . but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//h2[@class='font-plus-2 m-b-half']/strong/text()
```

**UPDATE:**
Looks there is space in the value for element `strong`, so you may normalize it as shown below:

```
//h2[@class='font-plus-2 m-b-half']/strong[normalize-space(.) = 'Book']
```

Comment: //*[@class='four columns m-r-3']//following-sibling::h2/strong[text()='Book']

Comment: //*[@class='four columns m-r-3']//following-sibling::h2/strong[text()='Book'] to this how to apply normalize-space ?

Comment: When i use                                                                                      normalize-space(//h2[@name='font-plus-2 m-b-half']/strong/text())

Comment: This is Working. //*[@class='four columns m-r-3']//following-sibling::h2/strong[normalize-space(.) = 'Book']      Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to know. Appreciate if you can accept it as answer.